# `onblur` event does not fire when user selects from the pop up menu

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events, onblur

I have a text box that lets the user select the zip code. If the user types on the zip code in the text box like 226016 and move away from the text box,  then `onblur` event fires and my JavaScript code is called.

I have a pick link button right next to the text box that opens up the popup menu that has the list of zip codes and it lets the user pick the zip code in case the user does not know the zip code. When the user selects the zip code from the pick menu and the zip appears in the text box, then none of the events fire if I click on another text box.

I want a JavaScript event to be fired when the user types in the zip code and moves away from the text box and when the user selects something from the popup menu and the zip code appears in the text box.

When the zip code appears from the popup menu to the text box, then even if I click on another text box, my JavaScript event does not get fired. I have an `onblur` event on my text box right now.

#### This is my code

```js
<asp:TextBox ID="TXTCode" runat="server" CssClass="txtReview" Width="30" MaxLength="2" onkeyup="javascript:HidePick(this);" onblur="javascript:TestThis(this);">

function TestThis(selectObj) {
    if (selectObj.value.toUpperCase() == "j1") {
        // do something 
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share parsed `HTML` ?

Comment: Um, why are you comparing an uppercase string to a non uppercase string?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't firing because you are comparing a `.toUpperCase()` string to `"j1"` and inherently non uppercase string.

Comment: sorry, this was just an example. I copied the JavaScript from another page of my application. Since it is a number, I removed the upper case.